# Por que os métodos implementados de uma interface não podem ser privados?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Quando implemento uma interface na minha classe, por que seus métodos implementados não podem ser privados/protegidos/etc?

E outra dúvida, quando implemento um método da interface explicitamente, por que esse método não pode ser `public`?

Exemplo:

```
interface IBaseInterface
{
    void ExampleMethod();
}

public class BaseClass : IBaseInterface
{
    public void IBaseInterface.ExampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.ExampleMethod();");
    }
}
```

Gera o erro:

> Error  1   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O propósito dos métodos privados é justamente esconder a implementação de alguma coisa. As interfaces servem para descrever um contrato que uma API deve ter. Contratos não se importam com implementações. Então não faz sentido ter métodos privados em interfaces.

Posto de outra forma, interfaces estabelecem que qualquer tipo que a implemente deve possuir aqueles métodos porque os consumidores daquele tipo esperam que aqueles métodos estejam lá, e obviamente podem ser acessados. Obrigar um tipo ter um método privado é ir além do contrato, é se meter no detalhe de implementação que só diz respeito ao tipo concretamente implementado. Já que o método não poderá ser acessado publicamente é problema só dele decidir se aquele método deve existir ou não.

Justamente porque todos os métodos de uma interface devem ser públicos, não faz sentido colocar esta informação porque ela já está implícita na interface.

Em C# 8 provavelmente poderá ter (algumas decisões foram adiadas para futura versão, mas já faz sentido), mas só porque as interfaces passarão contar com implementação, e o método privado só poderá ser chamado por um método implementado na interface. Provavelmente poderá ter método protegido também, aí o método poderá ser chamado pela classe que implementar esta interface. Quando tiver sido lançado vamos falar sobre isto (faça uma pergunta sobre interfaces com implementação).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Porque não faz sentido.

A função de uma interface é expôr métodos através de um contrato para outras entidades e sistemas. Sendo assim, não há necessidade dessas outras entidades conhecerem métodos privados, até porque eles não serão usados por essas outras entidades.

Quando uma classe implementa uma interface, isto não significa que tudo o que for declarado na interface deva ser implementado na classe, até porque isso inviabilizaria uma classe implementar múltiplas interfaces. Por exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasse: IMinhaInterface1, IMinhaInterface2 { ... }
```

No seu caso, seu código pode perfeitamente ficar assim:

```
interface IBaseInterface
{
    void ExampleMethod();
}

public class BaseClass : IBaseInterface
{
    public void ExampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.ExampleMethod();");
    }

    private void AnotherMethodThatDoesntNeedToBeKnown() 
    {
        // Como o método é privado, só a classe precisa acessar.
        // Veja que não há necessidade de ele ser exposto em uma interface.
    }
}
```