# Private set de propriedade em uma interface

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, interface, propriedade

Estou modelando uma interface em C# que possui uma propriedade. Porém, quero garantir que todas as classes que implementarem essa interface mantenham o *setter* como privado:

```
public interface IBar
{
    string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Esse código não compila, apresentando a seguinte mensagem:

> accessibility modifiers may not be used on accessors in an interface

Qual alternativa para garantir o *setter* privado para essa propriedade?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Interfaces devem definir contratos públicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58891/101), por isto não faz sentido ter um membro privado nela.

Pelo menos até agora. Há propostas provavelmente para o C# 8 das interfaces permitirem implementações e aí faria sentido ter membros privados, embora o nome interface comece perder o sentido.

No momento você deve simplesmente ignorar o membro privado, se é privado é detalhe de implementação, então deixe a classe decidir sobre isto. Quando a interface se comportar como um *trait* o membro privado será detalhe da interface (no C# 8 ainda há limitações nisso, mas já avançou, quem sabe mais pra frente tenha mais, não tem previsão). Provavelmente terá um membro protegido, aí poderá fazer o que está pretendendo, mas há controvérsias sobre o uso de membro protegido, ainda mais em uma interface, ainda que ela deixe de ser uma interface.

```
public interface IBar {
    string Id { get; }
}

class Foo : IBar {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/PrivateInterface.cs).

Answer (score 6):

O mais seguro é você definir apenas `get`; com isso quem implementar a interface não terá opção de alterar o valor.

```
public interface IBar
{
    string Id { get; }
}
```

Quem implementar a interface poderá definir seu próprio `private set`, como mostrado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250010/4551469). Exemplo:

```
class Bar: IBar
{
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Segundo [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249981/how-do-you-implement-a-private-setter-when-using-an-interface) resposta, você define apenas o `getter` da propriedade:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

E pode extende-la na classe para ter um `setter` privado:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```