# É possível obrigar uma classe a implementar um atributo em Java?

Tags: java, interface, campos

É possível obrigar uma classe a implementar um atributo no Java?

Eu sei que através de interfaces você consegue obrigar a classe a implementar métodos, porém gostaria de fazer isso com atributos também.

Ou se não for possível obrigar a classe a ter o atributo, pelo menos exibir um Warn na IDE avisando que aquele atributo deve ser implementado igual acontece quando implementamos a interface `Serializable`, onde a IDE fica dando *warning* até implementarmos o `serialVersionUID`;

Comment: Cita o exemplo real ... um exemplo minimo...

Comment: eu criei uma interface chamada Indentifiable, essa interface tem os métodos getId() e setId() que obrigam a implementação desses métodos, porem eu queria botar também o campo ID pra obrigar a também ter ele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está chamando de [atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Eu entendo que tenha aprendido assim porque tem muito material errado.

Um campo privado é detalhe de implementação e por isso só o tipo que precisa dele deve ter seu conhecimento. Não sendo público não tem porque obrigar fazer qualquer coisa, é decisão do implementador usar ou não um campo privado para obter o resultado desejado. [Interfaces não podem dizer nada sobre a parte privada de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58891/101).

Se está falando de um campo público [não pode porque interfaces são só sobre comportamentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101) (pelo menos o contrato deles). Inclusive tem implicações técnicas que dificultam bastante fazer isso. E será que deveria ter um campo público?

Se realmente quer forçar um contrato que tenha um determinado dado você pode colocar na interface um [método *getter* e outro provavelmente *setter*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) que em tese obrigaria o implementador criar o campo privado desejado. Nada impede que a classe habilite o comportamento necessário que a interface exija de outra forma, mas em alguns casos não tem como não ser assim. Isso pode deturpar um pouco o propósito do objeto, mas se a definição do problema realmente exige esse dados exposto assim, então é uma boa solução. Só acho que muitas vezes a definição do problema está errada.

[Criar um *getter/setter* pode ser abuso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204355/101).

Você pode criar algum adendo ao IDE que informe isso analisando seu código, mas não costuma ser vantajoso. Parece haver uma concepção errada de como usar a interface, então provavelmente seria um erro fazer algo assim.